# pandas fill missing values with mean of other columns grouped by a value

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I have this dataset where I have NaN values on column 'a'. I want to group rows by 'user_id', compute the mean on column 'c' grouped by 'user_id' and fill NaN values on 'a' with this mean. How can I do it?

this is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, np.nan, np.nan], 'user_id': [1, 2, 2], 'c': [3, 7, 7]})

print(df)
```

what I should have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 7, 7], 'user_id': [1, 2, 2], 'c': [3, 7, 7]})
    
    print(df)
```

what I've tried

```
df['a'].fillna(df.groupby('user_id')['a'].transform('mean'), inplace=True)

print(df)
```

after printing the df I still se NaN on 'a' column

Note since I have a huge dataset I need to do id inplace

Answer (score 0):

I think you need processing column `c`:

```
df['a'].fillna(df.groupby('user_id')['c'].transform('mean'), inplace=True)
df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(df.groupby('user_id')['c'].transform('mean'))
print (df)
     a  user_id  c
0  0.0        1  3
1  7.0        2  7
2  7.0        2  7
```

Comment: I've tried but I still see NaN on 'a' column

Comment: Based on the df provided, this solution seems to work as intended (for me)